# Как правильно написать в заявлении: допустить до сдачи экзамена или к сдаче экзамена?

Tags: грамматика

"Допустить до" или "допустить к"? Как правильно?

Answer (score 4):

В Большом толковом словаре под редакцией Кузнецова эти варианты синонимичны. **ДОПУСТИТЬ,** к чему (до чего) или с инф. Дать разрешение пользоваться, заниматься чем-л., принять участие в чём-л. Д. к работе. Д. к конкурсу. ***Д. студента к экзаменам, до экзаменов.***

Answer (score 0):

Насколько понимаю, грамматически тут никак не регламентируется, варианты синонимичны и по сочетаемости с предлогом вполне проходят.

"На слух" же вариант "допустить до" кажется мне более правильным в сочетании со сдачей, как неким действием. Т.е. я бы предпочел "допустить к экзамену", но "допустить до сдачи".  Субъективно, наверное.

Answer (score 0):

> Как правильно написать в заявлении: допустить до сдачи экзамена или к
>   сдаче экзамена?

**Верны оба варианта.** Я бы выбрал этот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я бы уверенно предпочёл "**допустить к экзамену** (= **к сдаче экзамена**)", и не только из-за сложившейся практики. "Синонимичность" вариантов, вероятно, выводят из сочетаемости предлога "до" с одноимённой приставкой в глаголе. Но это действует не для всех глаголов, если исходить из смысла, а не из формальной похожести предлога на приставку. Не возникает сомнений с таким глаголом, как "**довести до** (какой-то стадии, отметки или величины)", где "до чего" может иметь *количественный* смысл. С глаголом же "допустить" более уместны варианты: к чему, куда, в какое место (допустить или не допустить), в то время как "количественный" смысл можно приписать только искусственной конструкции со значением "*подпуская, **допустить** кого-то (что-то) до некоторой отметки шкалы - **докуда**"*. Посколько в аспекте "допустить или нет" экзамен не трактуется как стадия учебного процесса (*допустить учащегося докуда, до какой вехи в обучении* - и только в этом смысле *до чего*), то выражение "*до*пустить *до* экзамена (=*до* сдачи экзамена)" мне представляется гораздо менее естественным.